# Thermal dissipation on TO-252-3 Package

Tags: thermal, surge-protection

I am in the process of designing a surge stopper with fault latchoff using LT4356.
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LT4356-3.pdf

I decide to use this MOSFET, which by the way it's the one used on datasheet of the LT4356.
The MOSFET is IRLR2908
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRLR2908-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153566cdace2681

This board will be designed for 11-12V input and 12V, 8A output using a 4 layer PCB and 1oz of copper in all layers.

During the output short circuit condition analysis with a 12V output and 0.934 ms of overcurrent fault time the power dissipation of the MOSFET is 96 W in my scenario (see more info on page 16 of the datasheet of the ic).
This 96 W are ok based on the SOA of the MOSFET (page 4 fig 8 of the mosfet datasheet).

I read this guideline for thermal management on DPAK packages
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/cd00004438-953624.pdf

Based on that document and making some approximations the drain pad surface will be according to my calculations 16x16cm to dissipate all the heat but that makes me doubt so much.
I never design a scenario which includes so much of power so I need anyone with experience that could tell me some tips, if I should use a heatsink for dpak and so.

Comment: 96 watts is a *lot* of power for a surface-mount part. Especially a relatively small DPAK. I would move to a through-hole part in TO-247 or TO-263 if you expect this to be an important mode of operation. At least look for something in a D²PAK or D³PAK.

Comment: Do you really mean 16 cm x 16 cm?

Comment: @Andyaka yes, but have in mind that this calcs could be wrong becasue I do not have so much experience in thermal topic. Also this scenario is in the event of a short circuit condition, In normal operation there won't be so much power

Comment: So, your transistor heatsink is 160 mm x 160 mm (6.3 inches by 6.3 inches) - doesn't that take up a lot of PCB room?

Comment: @Andyaka yes, like you said for me is a lot of pcb room, so I need some improvements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at it from a steady-state heat generation perspective, which is why you're getting frankly impossible numbers.  As the LT4356 datasheet says (and it looks like you've done), you need to consider the MOSFET's SOA envelope when selecting a pass element.  When "long duration" means 100ms, there's simply not enough time for a lot of heat to make it out of the package, much less into your land.  Yes, adding copper will help during transients, but the biggest thing it does is let the MOSFET cool off back to ambient after the transient has occurred.

Which leads us to the app note: if you look at fig. 6, you'll see an asymptote around 50C/W for the DPAK package.  After a certain distance from the package, adding more copper won't help you since the thermal gradient has leveled out and any new copper is sitting at ambient.  You lay down thicker copper, add thermal vias, etc but they're not going to make 25600mm^2 of land effective when the Rth curve has pretty much leveled out two orders of magnitude before that.

As for your part selection, I think you'd be better served with a more robust pass element.  The "typical application" part is for a 4A application and you're doing twice that.  As Hearth suggested, something in a bigger package would serve you better.